# Performance issue with UIDatePicker with insertRowsAtIndexPaths iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uidatepicker

I'm developing an app where the user should be able to set a start and stop time with a UIDatePicker that is shown/hidden when row is pressed. I do this by inserting the UIDatePicker below the touched row. When I run the app in the simulator everything works smooth and nice, but when I try it on a real device, it takes around 2 seconds for the UIDatePicker to appear. The picker loads slow on both "start" and "stop" time once, but after that it will go back to normal loading time when showing/hiding it again. I'm wondering what could be the issue here.

This is the didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    if (indexPath.section == dataSection) {
        if ((indexPath.row != self.pickerIndexPath.row && self.pickerIndexPath != nil) || self.pickerIndexPath == nil) {
           [self togglePicker:indexPath]; //<--- This one takes up to two seconds
        }
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == buttonSection && indexPath.row == 0) {
        [self registerTime];
    }
}
```

And here is togglePicker:

```
- (void)togglePicker: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    NSArray *indexPathArray;

    if (self.pickerIndexPath != nil) {
        //Should remove old one first
        NSArray *indexPathArray = @[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.pickerIndexPath.row inSection:dataSection]];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

    if (indexPath.row + 1 != self.pickerIndexPath.row) {

        NSInteger rowDiff = 1;
        if ([self isUnderPicker:indexPath]) {
            rowDiff = 0;
        }

        indexPathArray = @[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row + rowDiff inSection:dataSection]];

        // --- These two lines below seems to have something to do with it
        // --- because if I comment these out the application never get stuck (otherwise 2 seconds)

        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        self.pickerIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row + rowDiff inSection:dataSection];


    }
    else {
        self.pickerIndexPath = nil;
    }

    [self.tableView endUpdates];
    [self givePickerStandardValues];
}
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath I simply return this which happens pretty fast so I don't think this should be an issue:

```
newCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:pickerCellID];
```

Any idea what could cause this long loading time for the picked on a real device the first times it appears? Thank you so much in advance!